# SQL Join after ordered select from CTE breaks order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I encountered this problem with SQL Server today and while I found the solution, I don't understand why/how it works so I am hoping to find some help here.

**TLDR**: let's define a CTE that loads data, this data is then ordered, OFFSET (for pagination), and finally joined with other tables. The problem was I lost the initial order after the join which is something I though could never happen.

Code (hugely simplified):

```
WITH _data AS 
(
    SELECT 
        O.*
    FROM 
        [Order].[Order] O
    WHERE 
        // Some complex filtering omitted for clarity
), 
_count AS 
(
    SELECT COUNT_BIG(0) AS TotalCount 
    FROM _data
)
SELECT 
    _orders.*,
    OI.Id, 
    OI.Amount as 'AmountDecimal', 
    T.TotalCount as 'TotalCount' 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM _data 
     ORDER BY
         CASE WHEN @SortByColumnName = 0 AND @SortOrder = 1
                  THEN _data.CreatedOn 
              ELSE '' 
         END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @SortByColumnName = 0 AND @SortOrder <> 1
                  THEN _data.CreatedOn 
              ELSE '' 
         END DESC
         // More order cases omitted for clarity
         OFFSET ((@Page - 1) * @Count) ROWS 
             FETCH NEXT @Count ROWS ONLY
    ) _orders
LEFT JOIN 
    [Order].[OrderItem] OI ON _orders.Id = OI.OrderId
CROSS APPLY 
    _count T
```

Running this query, in some cases, my ORDER BY got broken in the final result. If on the other hand, I copy the whole order by section and put it below CROSS APPLY (effectively sorting twice), it starts working again.

My question is, why is this necessary? I would have though the order defined by the initial order by clause should be honored.

Also please note this only breaks under some (based on my knowledge random) circumstances. It's definitely not predictable.

SQL Server Version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU25) (KB5003830) - 14.0.3401.7 (X64) Jun 25 2021 14:02:48   
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation     
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: The only order by which affects the query result is the outer/last one. The order by for your sub-query is **only** used by the `OFFSET/FETCH` part of the sub-query. But has no effect on the outer query.

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, you describe the results you want, not (usually) how to get there; your entire query, including any CTEs, sub-queries etc are broken down into a complex algebraic tree that's examined with some very clever optimisations to build an execution plan; every table, physical or derived, is an unordered set and you can't make assumptions about any ordering applied except when defining the result set.

Comment: add a Order by, as result sets are by nature unsorted

Comment: Cheers guys, what threw me off was the fact that 99% of the time, the inner order by worked for the end result too. It feels a bit off that I have to repeat this order by code, I wonder if this could be somehow simplified (in terms of the code). But I am happy with the answers, I learned something today! :)